# How to find on which node is a specific index on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch server with thousands of indexes. My question is how can I know on which node is my index saved on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [cat shards API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html#cat-shards).

```
GET /_cat/shards/index-name
```

It will return where the shards of the `index-name` is located.